# Errors installing jupyter with PIP on windows

Tags: pip, jupyter

I am trying to install jupyter with PIP. I am running on Windows 10 Enterprise with python 3.12.0, pip 23.2.1.

I get the following error from pip install jupyter

```
Collecting pywinpty (from jupyter-server<3,>=2.4.0->notebook->jupyter)
  Using cached pywinpty-2.0.11.tar.gz (26 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [6 lines of output]

      Cargo, the Rust package manager, is not installed or is not on PATH.
      This package requires Rust and Cargo to compile extensions. Install it through
      the system's package manager or via https://rustup.rs/

      Checking for Rust toolchain....
      [end of output]
```

I then tried installing the Cargo and Rust packages. I was able to install Cargo, but got the following error for pip install Rust

```
PS C:\Users\moodya03> pip install Rust
Collecting Rust
  Using cached RUST-1.3.1-py3-none-any.whl (49 kB)
Collecting pysam (from Rust)
  Using cached pysam-0.22.0.tar.gz (4.6 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [39 lines of output]
      # pysam: cython is available - using cythonize if necessary
      # pysam: htslib mode is shared
      # pysam: HTSLIB_CONFIGURE_OPTIONS=None
      '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
      operable program or batch file.
      '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
      operable program or batch file.
      Makefile:142: htscodecs.mk: No such file or directory
      make: uname: Command not found
      Makefile:326: Extraneous text after `else' directive
      Makefile:329: Extraneous text after `else' directive
      Makefile:329: *** only one `else' per conditional.  Stop.
      # pysam: htslib configure options: None
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\moodya03\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "C:\Users\moodya03\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\moodya03\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\moodya03\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-build-env-s8kcfoba\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 355, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\moodya03\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-build-env-s8kcfoba\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 325, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "C:\Users\moodya03\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-build-env-s8kcfoba\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 507, in run_setup
          super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend, self).run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
        File "C:\Users\moodya03\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-build-env-s8kcfoba\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 341, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 442, in <module>
        File "<string>", line 82, in run_make_print_config
        File "C:\Users\moodya03\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\subprocess.py", line 466, in check_output
          return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\moodya03\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\subprocess.py", line 571, in run
          raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
      subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['make', '-s', 'print-config']' returned non-zero exit status 2.
      [end of output]
```

Can someone please suggest a workaround to get jupyter installed that does not require Anaconda?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Steps to Resolve

The pywinpty package requires Rust and Cargo to compile extensions. These tools cannot be installed using pip. You can download them from the official Rust website and add them to your PATH.

1. Install Rust and Cargo from rustup.rs.
2. Make sure the Rust/Cargo binaries are in your system's PATH.
3. Retry installing Jupyter via pip

.

Comment: As an FYI to others, seems the auto install of visual studio as part of the Rust install no longer functions and must be installed separately first.